# PDF file generated not compatible with IEEE check

Tags: ieeetran

I generated a pdf file using IEEEtran and tried to check my file in ieeepdfexpress and my paper failed. The following were the errors I got.

Any help would be appreciated

Error message:
Font Arial, Times New Roman, Times New Roman,Italic is not embedded (188x on pages 2,4)

Comment: How do you generate your pdf, with `pdflatex`?  If you are using TeXLive, what is the result if you enter `updmap-sys --showoption pdftexDownloadBase14` in your shell?

Comment: Are you including figures or images? If so, what format are they in?

Comment: @Arash Esbati - I am not very familiar with shell. I am using texmaker for generating my files. Also, I am using pdftex.

Comment: @cfr - I have jpeg and png file types.

Comment: @user2981841 - texmaker is only an editor; you need a tex distribution to compile your file(s).  Depending on your OS it might be MiKTeX, TeXLive, MacTeX etc.  A command shell is a interface to your OS; depending on your OS it might be bash, cmd.exe etc.

Comment: @Arash Esbati - Thank you for your clarification. I am using miktex. I tried your command in the comand prompt, but I received an error saying that updmap-sys is not recognized as a command.

Comment: @user2981841 - `updmap-sys` is a script in TeXLive.  In MiKTeX, you might try `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` and check the value of `pdftexDownloadBase14` when the editor pops up. (N.B. I don't use MiKTex).

Comment: There is something odd about this anyway. If you are using pdfTeX, it is very unlikely that your document would use Arial or Times New Roman or whatever, embedded or not. When you view the PDF in your PDF viewer, what fonts are listed under Properties, what type are they and are they embedded?

Comment: Some of my figures are drawn in visio and then converted to png. If I use figures drawn from another source, I am able to successfully pass the check. I guess the problem is with the figures generated by visio.